# GStreamer Runtime Error

Tags: c++, cmake, gstreamer

It tried to run a GStreamer Tutorial Example, that already worked, but didn't work anymore right now. I didn't change the source code. I build the Project with CMake.

I get the following Error on every of my Testprograms, that are slightly different from each other:

```
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_param_spec_boxed: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_BOXED (boxed_type)' failed
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_class_install_property: assertion `G_IS_PARAM_SPEC (pspec)' failed
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gsignal.c:1644: parameter 1 of type `<invalid>' for signal "GstAppSrc::push_buffer" is not a value type
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GstObject'
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion `parent_type > 0' failed
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_class_set_static_metadata: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass)' failed
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_ref: assertion `GST_CAPS_REFCOUNT_VALUE (caps) > 0' failed
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_ref: assertion `GST_CAPS_REFCOUNT_VALUE (caps) > 0' failed
(GStreamer_Test_AppSrc:28073): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_unref: assertion `GST_CAPS_REFCOUNT_VALUE (caps) > 0' failed
```

Answer (score 4):

The Problem was, that i had installed GStreamer 0.10.x AND 1.x and mixed together both respectively CMake.

CMake remembered some Cache Settings, when i tried to compile my Project with GStreamer 1.x. After cleaning up the Out-of-Source Build Directory of the CMake-Project and rebuilt the Project again with solely GStreamer-0.10.x Dependencies, my Programs again worked as expected.